# How to retrieve an int-type data from firebase to xcode? (Error: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int')

Tags: swift, xcode

I was trying to fetch data from firebase to my xcode project. The only fields I have are 'userName', 'age', and 'number'. I was trying to append the values into arrays `userNames`, `ages`, and `numbers`. However, I get the error `Error: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int` in the appending age and number lines. They both have been entered as `Int` types in the database.

I thought about converting the values of the database into `Int` types since I think Xcode is taking them as `String` types? I tried, but I think my code itself was wrong so I couldn't solve it. I would appreciate the help!

```
    func fetchData () {
        let database = Firestore.firestore()
        database.collection("users").addSnapshotListener {(snap, Error) in
            if Error != nil {
                print("Error")
                return
            }
            for i in snap!.documentChanges {
                let documentID = i.document.documentID
                let userName = i.document.get("userName")
                let age = i.document.get("age")
                let number = i.document.get("number")
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    self.userNames.append("\(userName)")
                    self.ages.append("\(Int(age))")       // error line
                    self.numbers.append("Int\(number)")   // error line
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what’s the type of ages array? it should be [String], same for numbers. If you want to append string values and not Int. Your current type seems to be [Int].

Comment: I want to append Int values. The data type of `age` and `number` is Int type in the database, and the arrays `ages` and `numbers` are Int as well. I don't know what is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to coerce the data into the types you want by using `as?`.  (`get` returns `Any?` by default)

```
let userName = i.document.get("userName") as? String
let age = i.document.get("age") as? Int
let number = i.document.get("number") as? Int
```

Keep in mind that you'll end up with Optional values, so you'll need to have a fallback in case you don't get the type you expect.

If you wanted to provide defaults, you could do:

```
let userName = i.document.get("userName") as? String ?? ""
let age = i.document.get("age") as? Int ?? 0
let number = i.document.get("number") as? Int ?? 0
```

Then, later:

```
self.userNames.append(userName)
self.ages.append(age)
```

Note that your compilation errors were happening because you were trying to store `String` values (`""`) in an `[Int]`

---

In general, rather than storing all of these in separate arrays, you may want to look into making a `struct` to represent your data and storing a *single* array with that type. See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67712824/560942

And, the Firestore documentation on custom objects: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects

Comment: I tried both the ways but it still showed the same error. It worked when I changed the arrays into String type. I think I will convert them to Int in some other function if I ever have to use them as an Int. I am super new to this, so thanks for the resources!

Comment: Make sure you're using the `then, later` part of my example -- the arrays wouldn't definitely not need to be `String` arrays (besides `userNames`). `ages` and `numbers` should be `[Int]` and my provided code will work fine.

Comment: It works now, thanks! However I got the error `Cannot convert value of type 'Any?' to expected argument type 'String'` for ` self.userNames.append(userName)`. It works when I don't coerce the data type for `userName` though.

Comment: Hmm -- `get` returns `Any?`. In my example (the second one), it's converted to `String`. Assuming `userNames` is `[String]`, it will work as expected, unless something's been changed from my examples. You can option-click on `userName` to see the type.

Comment: I am not quite sure what it was, but after clearing and building again, it worked. Thank you again!